# grub2-install can't find lvm device

Tags: fedora, lvm

I am in the process of moving from Arch to Fedora and simplifying my partitioning scheme in the process (by using LVMs raid options instead of layering it on an mdadm array). I have this LVM scheme:

```
$ lvscan
  ACTIVE            '/dev/dragon/fedora' [20.00 GiB] inherit
  ACTIVE            '/dev/dragon/swap' [32.00 GiB] inherit
  ACTIVE            '/dev/dragon/home' [3.59 TiB] inherit
```

All three LVs are raid10 across four 2TB harddrives. Fedora has installed with minimal pain, except that it didn't install a bootloader on to any of the four PVs. So, I am attempting to install it manually by chrooting into the installed system from the live USB. I get this recurring error:

```
# grub2-install /dev/sdb
Installing for i386-pc platform.
grub2-install: error: disk ‘lvmid/uCln3P-NLvn-Hfj8-11nF-2R3l-prtW-goyTVJ/FpF3b4-LYI9-chju-Tcwc-uTSv-D6ZU-DAQIui’ not found.
```

It get the same error from `grub2-mkconfig`, but it generates the config file anyway. `grub2-install` does *not* appear to write to the MBR following this error.

This is my `/etc/default/grub`, although it appears to not make a difference - I get the same error if `GRUB_PRELOAD_MODULES` is empty, non existent, or contains nonsense:

```
GRUB_PRELOAD_MODULES="lvm mdraid1x"
```

The UUIDs in the lvmid disk name correctly match those on the VG and the LV. Why can't grub find the logical volume?

Answer (score 1):

i'm currently working on a similar problem in SLES12.1 and noticed that changing the device map to the corresponding PV makes grub2-install find the right disk:

```
$ cat /boot/grub2/device.map
(hd0)   /dev/vda
$ grub2-install /dev/vda --target=i386-pc
Installing for i386-pc platform.
Installation finished. No error reported.
```

In your case `vda` would be `sdb`

HTH